Managed Metadata fields display numbers instead of values
After applying a recent patch in our SharePoint environment, I've encountered an issue with Managed Metadata fields. When selecting a document, the actual values of these fields no longer appear in the information panel. Instead, a number is displayed (which I assume is the internal representation of the value).
The values are displayed correctly in edit mode, and it is possible to save and edit the values as normal. Also, this issue only seems to occur with fields that are set as required.

Is this a known issue, and is there any fix? Or is this a bug introduced by the latest patch?
We are using SharePoint SE (on premise).
Thanks in advance.

Which CU did you install? I am using 16.0.17328.20510 (August 2024), it works well. Besides, does this issue occur on a specified library or all libraries? All sites haves this issue? Have you tried created a new library with the same columns to check if this issue occurs on the new one?

We have been troubleshooting this exact issue today in SharePoint 2019 and SE farms with the August 2024 CU installed. This bug occurs in the display form (aka the panel on the right) on lists in the modern experience for Managed Metadata and Lookup columns that are a required field as part of a content type.
If we toggle the column to optional in the content type on the list we can see the value in the display form. If we remove the content type and add the field directly to the list it doesn't matter if it is optional or required, it shows the value either way.
We have a SharePoint SE farm with the June 2024 CU as well and the bug does not occur here so it seems it was introduced in the July 2024 or August 2024 CU.

There are a few steps you can take to resolve it:

Clear Browser Cache: Sometimes, clearing your browser cache can
resolve display issues.
Re-index the List: Go to the list settings and re-index the list.
This can help refresh the metadata.
Check Term Store Permissions: Ensure that your account has the
necessary permissions in the Term Store. Navigate to the Term Store
Management Tool and verify your permissions.
Update the Managed Metadata Service: Restart or update the Managed
Metadata Service Application in Central Administration.
Switch to Classic Experience: If you’re using the modern experience,
try switching to the classic experience to see if the issue
persists.
Recreate the Column: As a last resort, consider deleting and
recreating the affected Managed Metadata column. This can sometimes
resolve issues with corrupted metadata fields.


Unfortunately, none of the above works except for #5, but classic experience is not an option. This error only affects the information panel in modern experience. All managed metadata columns across all site collections for all users are affected.
